NaN loss when training LSTM-Attention
During model training, the loss value suddenly became Nan. Even though I change the parameters a lot, it still failed.
I checked the error when training and it prints the error in the output, not the input, so I think the error is in the parameters or my model.
>>> model_name: atae_lstm
>>> dataset: comment
>>> optimizer: <class 'torch.optim.adam.Adam'>
>>> initializer: <function kaiming_normal_ at 0x0000022D0817E0C0>
>>> lr: 1e-08
>>> dropout: 0.1
>>> l2reg: 0.01
>>> num_epoch: 10
>>> batch_size: 8
>>> log_step: 10
>>> embed_dim: 300
>>> hidden_dim: 300
>>> bert_dim: 768
>>> pretrained_bert_name: bert-base-uncased
>>> max_seq_len: 85
>>> polarities_dim: 3
>>> hops: 3
>>> patience: 5
>>> device: cuda
>>> seed: 1234
>>> valset_ratio: 0
>>> local_context_focus: cdm
>>> SRD: 3
>>> model_class: <class 'models.atae_lstm.ATAE_LSTM'>
>>> dataset_file: {'train': './datasets/comment/train.raw', 'test': './datasets/comment/test.raw'}
>>> inputs_cols: ['text_indices', 'aspect_indices']
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
epoch: 0
loss: 1.4378, acc: 0.1375
loss: 1.4600, acc: 0.1125
loss: 1.4595, acc: 0.1167
loss: 1.4558, acc: 0.1187
loss: 1.4623, acc: 0.1125
loss: 1.4695, acc: 0.1062
loss: 1.4511, acc: 0.1232
loss: 1.4533, acc: 0.1203
loss: 1.4610, acc: 0.1139
loss: 1.4598, acc: 0.1150
loss: 1.4659, acc: 0.1102
**loss: nan, acc: 0.1073
loss: nan, acc: 0.1077
loss: nan, acc: 0.1152
loss: nan, acc: 0.1133**
[[ 74   0   0]
 [ 90   0   0]
 [367   0   0]]
> val_acc: 0.1394, val_f1: 0.0815
>> saved: state_dict/atae_lstm_comment_val_acc_0.1394

input for model
text_indices = tokenizer.text_to_sequence(text_left + " " + aspect + " " + text_right)
text_indices = text_indices[:tokenizer.max_seq_len]  # Truncate if longer than max_seq_len
aspect_indices = tokenizer.text_to_sequence(aspect)
aspect_indices = aspect_indices[:tokenizer.max_seq_len]

input_colses = 'atae_lstm': ['text_indices', 'aspect_indices'],

This is LSTM-ATTENTION model
from layers.attention import Attention, NoQueryAttention
from layers.dynamic_rnn import DynamicLSTM
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

from layers.squeeze_embedding import SqueezeEmbedding


class ATAE_LSTM(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, embedding_matrix, opt):
        super(ATAE_LSTM, self).__init__()
        self.opt = opt
        self.embed = nn.Embedding.from_pretrained(torch.tensor(embedding_matrix, dtype=torch.float))
        self.squeeze_embedding = SqueezeEmbedding()
        self.lstm = DynamicLSTM(opt.embed_dim * 2, opt.hidden_dim, num_layers=1, batch_first=True)
        self.attention = NoQueryAttention(opt.hidden_dim + opt.embed_dim, score_function='bi_linear')
        self.dense = nn.Linear(opt.hidden_dim, opt.polarities_dim)
        #self.activation = nn.ReLU()  
        self.activation = nn.Tanh() 


    def forward(self, inputs):
        text_indices, aspect_indices = inputs[0], inputs[1]
        x_len = torch.sum(text_indices != 0, dim=-1)
        x_len_max = torch.max(x_len)
        aspect_len = torch.sum(aspect_indices != 0, dim=-1).float()

        x = self.embed(text_indices)
        x = self.squeeze_embedding(x, x_len)
        aspect = self.embed(aspect_indices)
        aspect_pool = torch.div(torch.sum(aspect, dim=1), aspect_len.unsqueeze(1))
        aspect = aspect_pool.unsqueeze(1).expand(-1, x_len_max, -1)
        x = torch.cat((aspect, x), dim=-1)

        # Ensure x_len is on CPU and of type int64
        h, (_, _) = self.lstm(x, x_len.cpu().to(torch.int64))
        ha = torch.cat((h, aspect), dim=-1)
        _, score = self.attention(ha)
        output = torch.squeeze(torch.bmm(score, h), dim=1)

        output = self.activation(output)  

        out = self.dense(output)
        return out

this is parameters I change
    if opt.model_name.lower() == 'atae_lstm':
        opt.batch_size = 8
        opt.num_epoch = 10
        opt.lr = 1e-8
        opt.initializer= 'kaiming_normal_'

